# How to calculate aggregate on inner join

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have two tables, Post & Comment. Post table contains info about posts & comment table contains the comments data about each post. Below is there structure,

```
Post Table
post_id (Primary Key), post_title, post_description

Comment Table
comment_id (Primary Key), comment_text, fk_post_id (Foreign Key)
```

I need to take post_id, post_title from post table and total no of comments (using aggregate function count) on each post from comment table & want the data to be showed like this.

```
Post_ID   Post_Title   Total_Comments
1         ABC           4 
2         XYZ           5
3         123           3
```

Total comments will be taken from the comments table by counting all the rows of a specific post_id.

I have managed to write a inner join query but dont know how and where to put aggregate function "count" to get total of all comments. Below is my query,

```
select post.post_id, post.post_title, comment.comment_id from post INNER JOIN comment on 
post.post_id = comment.fk_post_id ;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just add a `GROUP BY` clause to your query that lists columns coming from the `post` table, and `count()` how many records belong to each group.

```
select 
    p.post_id, 
    p.post_title, 
    count(*) no_comments
from post p
inner join comment c on p.post_id = c.fk_post_id
group by p.post_id
```

Note that I added table aliases to the query, to make it shorter to read and write.

We can avoid filtering out posts that have no comments with `left join`:

```
select 
    p.post_id, 
    p.post_title, 
    count(c.fk_post_id) no_comments
from post p
left join comment c on p.post_id = c.fk_post_id
group by p.post_id
```

You could also use a subquery for this, which avoids the need for outer aggregation:

```
select 
    p.*,
    (select count(*) from comment c where p.post_id = c.fk_post_id) no_comments
from post
```

Comment: First answer doesn't show the row if there is no comments but the second answer does

Comment: @bryan: yes that's correct. I updated my answer with a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT post.post_id
,post.post_title
,COUNT(comment.comment_id) as Total_coments 
FROM post 
INNER JOIN comment on  post.post_id = comment.fk_post_id 
GROUP BY post.post_id, post.post_title
```

I would strongly suggest reading about [aggregate functions.](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx)